# UnknownServerException: Element is not clickable at point (X, Y)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm write acceptance tests for the application created by using [Yii Framework 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii). I'm using [Codeception](http://codeception.com) and [Selenium software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)).

The problem is as follows.

On the page there is a `div` and if click on it - a menu will appear on the side. In that menu there is a link that I need.

That's part of the html code:

```
<div class="nav_panel">
    <div class="menuButton" id="np1" title="Menu"><b>Main menu</b><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
            <div class="np np5" id="np5" title="Tree" onclick="window.location.href = '/roles/controllermodule/tree'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollUp" class="npt glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up" title="Up"></div>
            <div class="np np6" id="np6" title="TestIt" onclick="window.location.href = '/gtest/gtest/index'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></div>
                <div class="np np7" id="np7" title="Clear DB Cache" onclick="$.ajax({type: 'GET',url: '/roles/role/schemarefresh'});">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></div>
            <div class="np np1" id="np2" title="Reports"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></div>
    <div class="np np2" id="np3" title="Documents"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
    <div class="np np3" id="np4" title="Profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
  </div>
```

Here is `di`v which I'm trying to click:

```
  <div class="np np3" id="np4" title="Profile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
```

In the test I can see that `div`:

`$I->seeElement(['xpath' => './/div[@id="np4"]']);`

But when I try to emulate a click on it - the test is failing with the error:

> [37;41m
>   [39;49m [37;41m  [UnknownServerException] unknown error: Element is
>   not clickable at point (21, 729). Other element would receive the
>   click:    (Session info:
>   chrome=50.0.2661.102)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 27 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-Q4B9M7G', ip: '.....', os.name: 'Windows
>   8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79' Session ID: ... Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WIN8_1, acceptSslCerts=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:...\scoped_dir11496_1013,
>   chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4)}, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   version=50.0.2661.102, takesHeapSnapshot=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]  [39;49m
>   [37;41m
>   [39;49m [33m Scenario Steps: [39m [1m 36.
>   $I->click(".//div[@id="np4"]")[22m at
>   [32mcodeception\acceptance\LoginCept.php:51[39m
>    35. $I->seeElement({"xpath":".//div[@id="np4"]"}) at [32mcodeception\acceptance\LoginCept.php:50[39m

I suggested that perhaps the image `glyphicon-user` overlaps the `div` element and tried to remove it in the test:

`$I->executeJS('$(".glyphicon-user").remove();');`

But it didn't help.

How can I emulate click on the `div` by using Codeсeption?

Comment: what is the error u are getting?

Comment: i think problem is in your element locator...in that case it would  be good if u give the element html portion

Comment: use this as cssSelector    div.np.np3#np4[title='Profile']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what helped me.

I deleted tag `span` as shown below and added delay:

```
$I->executeJS('$(".glyphicon-user").remove();');
$I->wait(10);

$I->click('div.np.np3#np4[title=\'Profile\']');
$I->wait(5);
```

Now everything is OK.

---

Also you may need to invoke `ng-click` action. For example, for button such as:

```
<button 
 type="button" 
 ng-click="addNewBlock(model.Languages)" 
 ng-hide="model.Languages.elem.length == model.Languages.max"   
 class="">Add</button>
```

This button dynamically adds blocks to the page. To invoke `ng-click` you can write:

```
$I->executeJS('$(\'button[ng-click="addNewBlock(model.Languages)"]\').click();');
```

If the button located at the bottom of the screen, you might want to perform scrolling there:

```
$I->executeJS('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);');
```

Checkboxes that scattered across the big page can create such a problem. To solve it, need to scroll the current element into the visible area of the browser window:

```
$I->executeJS('document.getElementById("some-id").scrollIntoView();'); 
$I->click('//*[@id="some-id"]');
```